# Invalid Initializer Error when initializing a pointer to a struct

Tags: c

I'm writing code for a `USB` bootloader. When I compiled the code, I got 2 of the following error:

```
Invalid Initializer
```

The error referred to the following lines of code:

```
static volatile usb_internal_sram_t sr;         
static volatile usb_internal_sram_t usb_sram = &sr;

usb_control_t ctr;                  
static usb_control_t usb_ctrl = &ctr;
```

Before someone suggests `malloc()`, this is an embedded system. Dynamic memory allocation is not advised as it can slow down the system. Hence, that is why I attempted to initialize the `struct` pointers this way. I thought this method would be ok, but apparently not. Anyone have any ideas? Thank you in advance!

Comment: "Initializing a pointer"? Where is the pointer??? I don't see any pointers being declared in your code. Why are you trying to initialize a struct object with a pointer value?

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the `*` token to declare your `usb_sram` and `usb_ctrl` objects as pointers.

Comment: Oh wow, I'm an idiot. I totally didn't notice I forgot the *.

Comment: Are you going to accept the answer? That would be the right thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

```
static volatile usb_internal_sram_t sr;
static volatile usb_internal_sram_t usb_sram = &sr;
```

you probably meant

```
static volatile usb_internal_sram_t sr;
static volatile usb_internal_sram_t* usb_sram = &sr;
```